# HTTP::script add me a folder to the path - Laravel

Tags: javascript, url, laravel-4, http-status-code-404

i want to add a reference to my scripts in a Laravel app. In my edit UI I have the reference like this:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/exam-definition.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/exam-definition-update.js')}}
```

The scrpits are in the folder: /public/js/exam-definition.js and the same for the other. But when I deploy in the browser the page give me this error:

[http://test.dev/public/exam/js/exam-definition.js?*=1406161079799*](http://test.dev/public/exam/js/exam-definition.js?_=1406161079799)
[http://test.dev/public/exam/js/messages.js?=1406161079800](http://test.dev/public/exam/js/messages.js?_=1406161079800)

You can see how the URL changes (because asset take), append an "exam" folder that dont exists. Is something wrong? I have this same ref to the scripts in another blade template and there is no error when deploy.
This are my controller method:

```
/**
 * Show the form for edit a Exam
 */
public function edit($id) {
    $exam = ExamService::examDefinition($id);
    $questions = $exam->getQuestions()->getResults();

    return View::make('exam.edit')
        ->with('exam', $exam)
        ->with('questions', $questions);
}
```

And the route for this page:

```
Route::get('exam/edit/{id}',    
    array('as' => 'exam_edit',      
           'uses' => 'ExamDefinitionController@edit'
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
{{ HTML::script('/js/exam-definition.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/js/exam-definition-update.js')}}
```

This will create a reference starting from the web root, and not from your current directory where the file is at. This also explains why your code could work from another blade template.

Comment: Hi, I try this route to, but there is the same error. I made a change to the route so I can test the app, and not stuck with this and try to resolv later. My route was Route::get('exam/edit/{id}', ...) and now I remove the edit from the route, like this: Route::get('exam/{id}', ...). With this last route the app charge the js fine, but with the other I dont know why added the "exam" before the js, since HTML::style putt in the public directory.